# Pass attribute via prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I pass an attribute (this attribute is from an entity) via prepareForSegue for a custom cell?

Consequently, I also have doubts about sending this attribute as filter through in accordance with the line that the user clicks? For example, in the first table the user clicks in the "Pizzeria", then the second screen is shown another table containing only establishments with the category "Pizzeria".

Here is my code so far

```
#pragma mark - Ações da tabela
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //O número de linhas da tabela será o mesmo número de objetos na lista de categorias
    return listaDeCategorias.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CelulaEstabelecimentoTableViewCell *celula = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IdentificadorCelula
                                                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(!celula) {
        celula = [[CelulaEstabelecimentoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                           reuseIdentifier:IdentificadorCelula];
    }

    categoria = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categoria" inManagedObjectContext:contexto];
    categoria.nome = [listaDeCategorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [celula.textLabel setText:categoria.nome];
    [celula setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return celula;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    categoria.nome = [listaDeCategorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSString *categoriaClicada = [listaDeCategorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:IdentificadorSegue sender:categoria.nome];
}

#pragma mark - Segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:IdentificadorSegue]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];
        EstabelecimentoViewController *destino = (EstabelecimentoViewController *)([navigationController viewControllers][0]);

    }
}
```

*Note: The prepareForSegue method is purposely incomplete because they do not know how to proceed from there.*

And here the custom cell I wish fill with filtered data
[image]

Mapped by:
[image]

Storyboard:
[image]

Comment: Can you show how your segue is connected in Storyboard?

Comment: I dont think you need another navigation controller, if you are not doing any thing special with you you can directly navigate from you cell to your destination controller, in your destination controller create a variable which you can set in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: @Qazi in this case, what type segue will be?

Comment: Simple push based (if you are not doing anything fancy, ) it would appear from right to left like a stanrd navigation

Comment: @Qazi I have set NavigationController to maintain navigation back, this case will not be lost, right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ViewController you are segueing too is EstabelecimentoViewController which has a public property "nome", this is how you would pass "nome" to EstabelecimentoViewController.nome:

```
#import 'EstabelecimentoViewController.h'
.
.
.
#pragma mark - Segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:IdentificadorSegue]) {
        EstabelecimentoViewController *establishmentVC = [segue destinationViewController];

        establishmentVC.nome = categoria.nome;
    }
}
```

Comment: EstabelecimentoViewController has TableView inside with an custom cell. I want that my attribute appears on custom cell.

Comment: You need to make it tableview data source and then add it, using that if you want to work that way

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Try This...*/
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"] && self.demoObject != nil) {
        // This line returns a value...
        NSLog(@"self.demoObject = %@", self.demoObject.itemDescription);
        // ...but it crashes here when it tries to set on the destinationViewController
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {
            SecondViewController *destinationViewController = (SecondViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
            destinationViewController.selectedItemPhoto = self.demoObject.photo;
            destinationViewController.selectedItemTitle = self.demoObject.itemDescription;
        }
    }
}
```